# sbt sonatypeRelease: Project URL missing, SCM URL missing, Developer information missing

Tags: scala, sbt, sonatype, sbt-sonatype

Trying to `sbt sonatypeRelease` a library gives this error:

```
2024-01-26 18:42:35.491+0300  info [SonatypeClient]     Failed: pom-staging, failureMessage:Invalid POM: /io/github/omitted/omitted_sjs1_3/0.3.6/omitted_sjs1_3-0.3.6.pom: Project URL missing, SCM URL missing, Developer information missing  - (SonatypeClient.scala:389)
```

What would be the needed setting's keys to put into my `build.sbt` to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following settings in your SBT definition (`build.sbt` typically):

```scala
// Project URL
ThisBuild / homepage := Some(url("https://yourwebsite.com"))

// SCM
ThisBuild / scmInfo := Some(
  ScmInfo(
    url("https://github.com/company/project"),
    "scm:git@github.com:company/project.git"
  )
)

// Developers 
ThisBuild / developers := List(Developer(...))

// License (example)
ThisBuild / licenses := List("MIT" -> url("http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"))
```